# How to start tomcat service automatically on windows server?

Tags: windows, tomcat, service

I want to start the tomcat service automatically  before user login,but I can not modify the settings in the services.msc. what can I do ?

Answer (score 1):

If you've installed Tomcat as a service, you can configure it to start automatically when the computer boots:

Start > Settings > Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Services (for open service)
then right Click "Apache Tomcat" > Properties
then Set "Startup Type" to Automatic
Now click Start or restart your pc

Comment: Can this service auto start before we login ?

Answer (score 0):

You must **login as administrator** to change items in `services.msc` . This is a tutorial about this: [How to Log in as an Administrator on Windows 7](http://www.ehow.com/how_8118587_log-administrator-windows-7.html)